# Regular Representation and Irreducible Representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

It seems every irreducible representation under certain carrier space $W\subset V$ (which is NOT a subspace of $\mathbb{C}G$), there always exists an isomorphism $g: W\rightarrow W_i$ where $W_i$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{C}G$ yielding an irreducible representation.

It seems to prove such a statement requires showing the existence of $g$ and $W_i$ simultaneously. Can somebody please give me proof of the existence of such an isomorphism?

*I don't have any background in the Field and Ring theory.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you proceed as follows: (I assume you speak of finite groups, as you use $\mathbb{C}G$)

You first derive a bit theory about characters, that is, for a (finite-dimensional) representation $\Gamma:G\to\text{GL}(V)$ just the trace. For these you have some sort of orthoginality relation, namely
$$
 \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G} \overline{\text{tr}\,\Gamma(g)}~\text{tr}\,\Gamma'(g)=\delta_{\Gamma,\Gamma'}
$$
for two irreducible representations $\Gamma:G\to\text{GL}(V),~\Gamma':G\to\text{GL}(V')$, where the $\delta_{\Gamma,\Gamma'}$ indicates that this sum equals 1 if the irreducible representations are the same (that is, equivalent, recalling the cyclicity of the trace), and 0 otherwise.

An arbitrary representation may now be decomposed into a direct sum of irreducible representations. The character of such a representation is then just summing the characters of the irreducible representations contained in that decomposition. So the above orthogonality representation may be used as a criterion "how many times a certain irreducible representation is contained in a given representation", since we just count "how many times the $\delta_{\Gamma,\Gamma'}$ is non-zero.

To the very end, you can just do that for the regular representation on $\mathbb{C}G$ and find that any irreducible representation with dimension $d$, occurs in the regular representation $d$ times. So you can conclude that for any ( $d$-dimensional) irreducible representation $\Gamma$ the $\mathbb{C}G$ contains $d$ $d$-dimensional subspaces (particularly one, which you had asked for), which pairwise only intersect in $\{0\}$ and on each of them the regular representation acts like $\Gamma$. The last part "acts like $\Gamma$" means that the regular representation, restricted to such a subspace, is equivalent to that given $\Gamma$. This equivalence then yields the isomorphism you had asked for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I also apologize for my not high enough reputation to cast the upvote.

Comment: Glad that I can help.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer, which I had chosen to be the proper answer to my question, turned out to be incomplete. Fortunately, I finally found the answer based on Ed Segal's lecture note on the representation theory.

The proof starts with the following two claims.

1. Denoting the vector space spanned by $G$-linear map $f:V\rightarrow W$ by $\mathrm{Hom}_G(V,W)$, the $\dim{\mathrm{Hom}_G(V,W)}=0$ counts the multiplicity of the irrep $W$ in $V$. The proof is immediate from Schur's lemma.
2. There is a natural isomorphism between $\mathrm{Hom}_G(V,W\oplus U)\approx\mathrm{Hom}_G(V,W)\oplus\mathrm{Hom}_G(V,U)$. The isomorphism is defined by $P: P(f)=(\pi_W\circ f, \pi_U\circ f)$.

Meanwhile, the statement I wanted to prove is as follows.

*Every irrep $W$ appears in the regular representation $V_{reg}$ whose multiplicity is determined by $\dim{W}$.*

The proof follows from demonstrating $\mathrm{Hom}_G(V_{reg},W)\approx W$. To prove this statement, we investigate the map defined by the evaluation at $e$ , i.e., $T:T(f)=f(e)$. Clearly, this map is linear.

Next, we investigate $\ker{T}$, i.e., some $f$ such that $f(e)=0$. Then by $G$-linearity, $0=\rho_Wf(e)=f(\rho_{V_{reg}}(e))=f(g)$ for any g. Thus $f$ must be zero map, and hence $T$ is injective.

Finally, we investigate $\mathrm{Im}T$. Suppose $w\in W$. Then if we define $f(g)\equiv\rho_W(g)(w)$, $f(\rho_{V_{reg}}(h)(g))=\rho_W(hg)(w)=\rho_W(h)f(g) $ and hence $f\in\mathrm{Hom}_G(V_{reg},W)$ and $T(f)=w$. Thus $T$ is surjective.

Hence $\mathrm{Hom}_G(V_{reg},W)\approx W$ and by the claim 1, $\dim{W}$ is the multiplicity of $W$ in thee regular representation.

Comment: @nicrot000 Oh, sorry if it upset you. I reaccepted your answer. To confess, when I accepted your answer, I did not read it all along thoroughly. Among your answer, "To the very end, you can just do that for the regular representation on CG and find that any irreducible representation with dimension d, occurs in the regular representation d times. " is what I exactly asked. And in that sense, I said the former one is incomplete.

Comment: @nicrot000 I want to make it clear that your answer was neither incorrect nor inappropriate. It is just my understanding about representation theory was at the (experimental) physicist level, and I just wanted to help other people just like me who will stop by this post by accepting mine which was the one with the more detailed explanation.